# Cannot acces wp-admin, one error left, how to solve this?

Tags: php, wordpress

I probably messed my wordpress site up by updating the site before updating plug ins, and now I cannot acces wp-admin anymore.
I got a number of error messages, most of which I could solve by changing something in the given file, but I do not know how to solve this:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "WP_Widget" not found in …/wp-content/plugins/category-posts/class-widget.php:22 Stack trace: #0 .../wp-content/plugins/category-posts/cat-posts.php(38): require_once() #1 .../wp-settings.php(359): include_once('...') #2 .../wp-config.php(90): require_once('...') #3 .../wp-load.php(37): require_once('...') #4 .../wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('...') #5 .../wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('...') #6 {main} thrown in .../wp-content/plugins/category-posts/class-widget.php on line 22

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue with one of your plugins, **category-posts**.

I would suggest, if you got access to the site's backend, navigate to `.../wp-content/plugins/` and delete the **category-posts** folder. This will delete the plugin which causes the issue, and hopefully resolve the problem. You can always download the plugin folder before deleting it, just so you've got it backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename category-posts plugin to any other name  so that the plugin will automatically deactivate. After that can you take a look to login to wp-admin. then from there try reinstalling  the same plugin or upload latest version of plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please see my 2nd post above.